# Can your landlord raise rent for running a business?

Tags: real-estate, florida

Say you run an academy from your house. Can your landlord raise rent? Nolo.com says

> Also, in most states your landlord can’t use a rent increase (or evict you or decrease services, either) in retaliation against you for exercising a specified legal right.

Is running a business exercising a legal right? It is legal, anyways. This is a month-to-month (lease-at-will) rental in Florida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be legal -- in many places zoning restricts running a business from a residential address.

If the academy involves physical students, the landlord could reasonably claim an increase in wear and tear, and liability risks.

In any case, with a month-to-month tenancy, the landlord can normally raise the rent with a month's notice for any reason or none.